# Visual Studio Code Automatic Preview Mode on Sidebar navigation?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, sublimetext

I've recently moved to Visual Studio Code from Sublime Text.

Something that I'm missing is the "automatic preview mode" (I don't know the exact name): in ST, if I navigate the files in the sidebar with the keyboard, every file is automatically opened in a (static) preview editor.

I couldn't find anything similar in VSC. The most similar functionality requires me to single-click, but I have two problems with this:

1. I'm a "keyboard-prevalent" user, and (single-)clicking defeats the purpose;
2. in ST this happens automatically, so it's faster anyway.

Am I missing something?

I've been searching for a while, but can't find anything relevant. It seems there are references to this functionality from Search Files (Ctrl+P), but I'm looking this functionality on the sidebar, since I use this while working on files of a single directory.

Answer (score 0):

VS-code works with extensions. If you cannot find the preview functionality you want, that is because the appropriate extension was not loaded.

So, if you want to preview Markdown, LaTeX, Excel files, or whatever, check the Extensions box in VS-code for the right extension and download it. Once the extension is loaded, you open the preview window and enjoy your preview. At the moment, VS-code is so mature that there is little you cannot preview in this way.